# ArrayList of HashSets iterating over indexes I don't specify?

Tags: java, primes, factoring

`isPrime()` checks if a number is prime, and `getPrimes(int upper)` gets all primes up to and including upper. I want `sievePrimeFactorSets` to make a HashSet of all the prime factors (no repeats) of each number, and to store that HashSet at the given value, e.g. the HashSet at `primeFactors.get(20) = [2,5]`.

Right now it adds *every prime* to *every* value, so `primeFactors.get(20) = [2,3,5,7,11,13,etc]`. Why is this happening?

```
public ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> sievePrimeFactorSets(int upper)
{
    ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> primeFactors = new ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>();
    HashSet<Integer> empty = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= upper; i++)
    {
        primeFactors.add(empty);
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> primes = getPrimes(upper);
    for (Integer p : primes)
    {
        for (int j = p; j <= upper; j+=p)
        {
            primeFactors.get(j).add(p);
        }
    }
    return primeFactors;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getPrimes (int upper)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    primes.add(2);
    for (int i = 3; i <= upper; i++)
    {
        if (isPrime(i))
        {
            primes.add(i);
        }
    }
    return primes;
}
```

Comment: suggest using `i += 2` instead of `i++` in your `getPrimes()` loop, 2 is the only even prime

Comment: Might I suggest that a `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>` might be better to use for this sort of thing than a `ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
primeFactors.add(empty);
```

adds the same empty hash set to each element of the array. So every element shares the same hash set and the changes you think you are making to one are actually made to all elements.

Just replace with:

```
primeFactors.add(new HashSet<>());
```

Comment: I love you. That answered it Giovanni. Also thanks Jason S, that'll speed it up.